# Particular Google Hangout window not opening

Tags: google-hangouts

A particular conversation (with just one person) is not opening up. I can see that there are new messages and read the last line in the conversations list, but the window just won't open.

What I tried doing that didn't (obviously) work:-

- Create a new conversation with that person (nothing happens);
- Trying both the Gmail website as well as the Chrome extension;

Googling gave me irrelevant results. What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It started working again after I cleared my browser's cache, but I'm not so sure that the correlation here implies causation. Oh well, another 'heisenbug' (non-reproducible irritation king of bug)...

Comment: It happened with me also. What I did was, I tried to open gmail in in-cognito mode, and it worked. I went to the previous window, I then logged out of the current gmail and tried again, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I tried logging out and logging back in.  Didn't work.  Then I tried clearing *some* things from the cache and it initially didn't work, but when I went back and added the "Cookies and other site and plug-in data" checkbox I was forced to log in again and it worked: annoying invisible hangout window re-appears.  So it seems to be related to the cookies cache data.

Comment: For me, i just had to refresh. I noticed that when i opened up a different conversation, there was space where the one i was trying to open should have been, as if it was really invisible. So i always had this conversation sized chunk of screen on the bottom right that other conversations would avoid like there was one there. Refreshing was all i had to do and boom it worked.

Answer (score -3):

Same happened here. It seems going into Gmail and logging out then back in fixed it.